# Users unable to see resource group in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm new to Azure AD. Got a few issues that say users are unable to see resource groups. (When they click on particular subscription -> resource group.) Is there any way to check? How to check which users can access or view the resource group which can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check the access for a user is to use the Check access feature on the Access control (IAM) page. See
[Quickstart: Check access for a user to Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/check-access?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)